# What's this foil dot near the foil stamp of a Magic card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I saw this photo of a Magic card with a shiny orb next to the oval one in the center. What's that mean?

[image: planeswalker wrenn]

Answer (score 8):

That is an Ultra Pro brand mark on the card sleeve.

You can see an example of them here:
[image: Ultra-pro pro-matte sleeve package]

Comment: That's really interesting.  Do they have them in the same place on both sides of the sleeve?

Comment: @LeppyR64 it would be rather odd to have sticker on both sides since this would immediatly make card "marked".

Comment: @Alex But if they're only on one side then you have to make sure they're always with the sticker on the face, otherwise they're marked.  On both sides at least all the cards are the same regardless of which way its loaded.

Comment: @LeppyR64 many sleeves are transparent on one face and opaque on the other, so that damage to any of the cards aren't marking them

Comment: In the the case of MTG the [tournament rules](https://wpn.wizards.com/en/document/magic-gathering-tournament-rules) also state the marking must be on the front face; `... cards must be inserted into the sleeves so these markings
appear only on the faces of the cards ...`

Answer (score 1):

The dot isn't on the card itself, but on the sleeve that card is in.

Ultrapro is a brand that makes a lot of gaming supplies, including sleeves. Each of their sleeves is stamped with that little foil circle on the transparent front side, 2cm from the right edge and 0.5cm from the bottom edge.

[image]

Comment: probably worth noting that not all Ultra pro sleeves carry the dot, and that it is not always located in the same place. the most recent dot move on the standard size sleeves was in 2018